# SQL Statement Match Anything

Tags: sql, replace, match

I use a regex in my SQL statements for an app that look like this

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = {{REPLACEME}}

However, sometimes I'm not giving a parameter to replace that string with. Is there a way to replace it with something that matches anything. I tried *, but that does not work.

Comment: I think the OP wants a regex string to use to match to anything.  if they wanted to rewrite the WHERE clause to something different, they could just eliminate it completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace {{REPLACEME}} with

```
[someValidValueForYouIdType] OR 1=1
```

Comment: This does work in this case, but if the predicate becomes more complex, you might get unwanted results due to operator precedence.

Comment: Yeah, but I presumed he wanted to get all results when no id is given. It sounds a little weird to me too, but I won't argue with his business logic.
I would just return null if no records are found. And probably use some kind of prepared statements instead of regex replacing.

Answer (score 7):

1. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id` will match all rows that have non-null `id`
2. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = id OR id IS NULL` will match all rows.

`id` is probably a primary key, so you can probably use the former.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the question. id = id is the same as no WHERE Clause.... (assuming NOT NULL restriction), right?

Comment: I think the OP has a bunch of SELECT statements of the form seen in the question; since we need to replace {{REPLACEME}} with something, it should be the identity.  Removing the WHERE clause would be better, but that's not what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I can only describe my solution with an example. The `@AllRec` is a parameter:

```
Declare @AllRec bit
set @AllRec = {0|1}  --as appropriate

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
   (
       id = {{REPLACEME}}
       and @AllRec = 0
   ) OR (
       @AllRec = 1
   )
```

In this solution, if `@AllRec` is 1 then everything is returned, ignoring the `id` filter. If `@AllRec` is zero, then the `id` filter is applied and you get one row.  You should be able to quickly adapt this to your current regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Regex-Replace option opens you up to SQL Injection attacks.

Assuming your language has support for parameterized queries, try this modified version of Jacob's answer:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (id = @id OR @id IS NULL)
```

The catch is that you'll always have to provide the @id value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM dbo.yourTable
WHERE id = isnull(@var, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language your using, and this code kind of scares me but...

```
var statement = "SELECT * FROM table";

If REPLACEME is not empty Then
   statement += " WHERE id = {{REPLACEME}}"
End If
```